# JavaScript: Перебор объекта с n-уровнем вложенности

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на чистом Javascript лучше перебрать объект имеющий определенный уровень вложенности? Например:

```
o = {"test1":
            {"val":
                        {"year":"1994"}
            },
     "test2":
            {"val":
                        {"body":"body1"}
            }
}
```

Я пробую так:

```
for (var key in o) {
    for (var k in o[key]) {
        for (var k1 in o[key][k]) {
                console.log(k1)
                console.log(o[key][k][k1])
        }
    }
}
```

Праильно ли я делаю? Или можно как-то проще?

Comment: Неа, используйте рекурсию. Вдруг будет объект вложенный на 7? А зачем Вам такой перебор?

Comment: @Other, Ok, А если фиксированный объект, как у меня в примере?

Comment: @Pavel , какова цель перебора?

Comment: @Other, br3t Мне нужно, получая JSON строку от сервера, и преобразовав ее в объект выбрать некоторые данные, затем эти данные записать в другой объект

Comment: Для этой вложенности можно и так (не забывая про `hasOwnProperty`, конечно). Хотя смотрится странно.

Comment: @Pavel , структура ответа извесна заранее?

Comment: @br3t, Да, структура в упрощенном варианте в примере.

Comment: если известна структура ответа, зачем перебирать объект... Берите необходимые свойства и пишите куда нужно.

Comment: Что-то типа `var newObj = {year: o.test1.val.year, body: o.test2.val.body}`

Comment: @pepel_xD, Структура известна, а набор данных нет.

Comment: @br3t, Это понятно. Но что если придет test3 с определенным набором данных? Нужен цикл

Comment: если нужен цикл используйте рекурсию. Т.е. получаете свойство объекта, проверяете является ли оно в свою очередь объектом, да получаете его первое свойство и т.д...... нет получаете значение

Answer (score 1):

```
function t(obj){
    if(/*объект*/){
        // Перебираем 
        for(var op in obj){
            t(op);
        }
    } else {
        // Делаем чтото из свойством обекта
        // Например 
        console.log(obj);
    }
}
```

Вот. Как то так если не ошибаюсь